# how to send an xmlhttprequest in cpanel shared hosting node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, cpanel

I wanna make a xhr on cpanel shared hosting in my client.My problem is that when i send xmlhttprequest to my url(example.com/chatttt/read) or /save i get service unavailable 503.as response. I wanna know whats the url the server will get the request. here is my server code :

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
const clientPath = `${__dirname}/client`;
app.use("/chatttt",express.static(clientPath));
const server = http.createServer(app);
console.log("app running!");
app.get('/read',async function(request, response) {
    console.log("readFileUrl : " + request.query.url);
    response.type("html");
    response.send(await getReadFile(request.query.url));
});
async function getReadFile(url){
    var Data;
    await readFile(url);
    async function readFile(filePath) {
        try {
          var data = await fs.readFile(filePath);
          Data = data;
          console.log(data.toString());
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Got an error trying to read the file: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
    return Data;
}
var fs = require("fs").promises;
app.listen();
```

And Client.js code :

```
var XHRS = [];
var i = 0;
SendRequest();
function SendRequest() {
    XHRS[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHRS[i].onload = function(){
        var ChatData = XHRS[i].responseText.split("\n");
        document.getElementById("ServerMessages").innerHTML = "";
        for (var j in ChatData) {
            var parent = document.getElementById("ServerMessages");
            var el = document.createElement("li");
            el.innerHTML = ChatData[j];
            parent.appendChild(el);
        }
        debugger;
        i++;
        setTimeout(SendRequest, 1000);
    }
    XHRS[i].open("GET", "/read?url=messages.txt", false);
    XHRS[i].send();
}
```

**Note that it will send read request each 1 second** My question is that what should i do? where should i adjust the url of the xhr? Or whats incorrect? Unfortunately i searched all the net about this but there wasnt any answer.So i asked on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Um... I don't really get you but I think you want to get the file content from the server but the server response 503 right?

Hence that 500+ HTTP response are server errors and have you tried using curl or postman to test your api because I usually do `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)`

I think the problems lies to the server

I hope it helps